# No suitable servers found: [connection refused calling ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017']

Tags: laravel, mongodb, xampp

No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection refused calling ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017']

**//.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=dba
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

**//database.php**

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options' => [
                'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'),
                'ssl' => false
            ]
        ],
```

**//Model**

```
class Question extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'questions';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'content','location'
    ];
}
```

**//php_info**

[php_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEfc.png)

I'm using XAMPP, LARAVEL 5.8, PHP 7.2 and MongoDB 1.7.3

Any solution?

Comment: Is the MongoDB running? Check the service. Have a look at your MongoDB logs, typically at /var/log/mongodb